# Open and Close App with VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have one project in VB.NET and this project have function to Open and Close another program like Calculator. I have successfully opened Calc.exe with code like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Shell("C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe")
End Sub
```

But when I try to create a function to close another program I dont't know how to write the code. This function is useful for closing programs that have already been opened with Button1.

Anyone can help me to make function to  close another program?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of shell you can use Process

```
Dim p As Process = Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe")

Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)

' Terminate after 10 seconds
p.Kill()
```

if you need to trigger killing the process somewhere then it needs access to the Process handle p.

OR if you want to kill any old process that you have not started you need to look into the `Process.GetProcessesByName()` which will give you an array of Process that you can then lop through and kill the relevant one.

Here is an example

```
   Dim myProcesses() As Process
    Dim myProcess As Process

    myProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("NameOfProcessAsString")

    Try

        If myProcesses.Length > 0 Then
            For Each myProcess In myProcesses
                If myProcess IsNot Nothing Then
                    myProcess.Kill()
                End If

            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
          Message.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```